# Java. Как разбить строку на отдельные значения и поместить значения в объект?

Tags: java, строки, scanner

Получаю на вход строку, которая вводится через Scanner:

```
C 1.1 8.15.1 P 15.10.2012 83
```

Мне нужно разбить эту строку так, чтобы `1.1` разбилось на 2 отдельных значения 1 и 1 и они поместились в определенные переменные в объекте.

То же самое с `8.15.1`, но остальные значения должны поместиться в объект целыми. Подвох в том, что эти два значения первое число имеют всегда, а остальных может не быть.

Comment: Перечитал раз 20, все равно не уверен, что понял задачу. Я понял в итоге так: приходит строка, в которой будет буква, пробел и пакеты целых чисел через точку, разделенные также пробелом; затем снова буква и тоже числа итд... Первый пакет чисел (после первой буквы) имеет строгий формат (ЧИСЛО.ЧИСЛО) без скобок. Остальные вообще могут не присутствовать? Правильно?

Comment: Не совсем. С(есть всегда без исключений), 1.1(вместо первой единицы может быть другое число, но в любом случае оно есть; а вот вторая единица(все так же не факт, что единица) может быть, а может и не быть) 8.15.1(то же самое, что и 1.1: первое число обязательно есть, а следующие два могут отсутствовать). После "Р" все всегда так, как в примере

Comment: а, теперь более менее ясно

Answer (score 0):

С помощью регулярного выражения все очень легко делается:

```
public class Application {

    public static final Pattern REGEX = Pattern.compile("C ([\\d]+).([\\d]+)[ \\d\\p{L}.]*");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matcher matcher = REGEX.matcher("C 12.1 8.15.1 P 15.10.2012 83");
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: А можете пояснить свой код? Ибо я пытаюсь понять как он должен работать. При запуске оно не находит совпадений в том, что вы написали

Comment: Регулярное выражение будет парсить строку которая начинается с буквы C(английской большой буквы), далее пробел. После пробела должно идти число, в котором цифр от одной и более, далее точка, опять число. А после могут идти, а могут и не идти такие элементы, как : пробел, число, буква или точка.

Comment: У меня все работает, находит одно совпадение, в первой группе число 12, во второй 1